# How to create shortcut to 2nd YouTube account

Tags: samsung, google-account, youtube, samsung-one-ui

How can I make a shortcut to a 2nd YouTube account on my Android phone. I have a Samsung s21+ with one ui 4.1 and Android 12

There is a dual messenger function which allows multiple versions of the same app to be installed. Can this be done with YouTube?

If not can I make two shortcuts, one that automatically loads a second YouTube profile and the other a default profile?

If this is not possible can I a make a chrome shortcut that opens the specific YouTube account in Chrome (or any other browser)

Ultimate goal is to have two icons, one for each profile so I don't have to keep switching profiles manually via the app (slow and requires 10+ seconds on slow internet).

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apps* available on google play and log in with the desired google account in the cloned app and then create a shortcut on the home screen.

*third-party cloner app as an alternative to Dual Messenger if it is not possible to duplicate youtube through it.

Comment: How exactly do I do this? Open YouTube then where do I go? Or do I open the play store and do something?

Comment: I will write an example using a third-party app (2Accounts), step by step:

1 - go to google play store and download an AppCloner (2Accounts suggested)

2 - open AppCloner and select YouTube to be cloned

3 - open cloned YouTube (maybe open by itself when cloned), go to library and login with your google account you want for the 2nd YT App

4 - open Appcloner again, press and hold the YT icon and press create shortcut/icon on home screen

5 - enjoy

Comment: Fantastic using 2Accounts worked perfectly. Thank you.